# PyCUDA Kernel returns inconsistent division result for specific calculations

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I'm trying to implement a kernel that calculates average of percentages.

Example- Taking the 3D array (in the code below) piece `[[2,4],[3,6],[4,8]]` and calculate `(4+6+8)/((4+6+8)+(2+3+4))`

Here's a colab notebook to run the following code quickly: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1k_XfOVOYWOTnNQFA9Vo_H93D9l-xWO8K?usp=sharing

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

# set dimentions
ROWS = 3
COLS = 2

h_perms = np.array([[
    [ 1,1],
    [ 1,1],
    [ 1,1]
],[
    [ 2,7],
    [ 3,11],
    [ 4,13]
],[
    [ 2,4],
    [ 3,6],
    [ 4,8]
],[
    [ 2,7],
    [ 3,11],
    [ 4,13]
],[
    [ 2,4],
    [ 3,6],
    [ 4,8]
],[
    [ 1,1],
    [ 1,1],
    [ 1,1]
]
], dtype=np.float32).flatten()

# send to device
d_perms = gpuarray.to_gpu(h_perms)

kernel = SourceModule("""
  __global__ 
  void calc(float *permutations, int *permutationShape, float *results)
  {
    __shared__ float c;
    __shared__ float b;
    int bIdx = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;
    int tIdx = threadIdx.y * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int rowCount = permutationShape[0];
    int colCount = permutationShape[1];
    int i = (bIdx * rowCount * colCount) + (tIdx * colCount);
    c += permutations[i];
    b += permutations[i+1];
    __syncthreads();
    results[bIdx] = b / (b + c);
  }
  """)

calc = kernel.get_function('calc')

# prepare results array
d_results = gpuarray.zeros((6,1), np.float32)
d_results = gpuarray.to_gpu(d_results)

h_perms_shape = np.array([ROWS,COLS], np.int32);
d_perms_shape = gpuarray.to_gpu(h_perms_shape);

start = cuda.Event()
end = cuda.Event()
start.record()
calc(d_perms, d_perms_shape, d_results, block=(ROWS,1,1), grid=(ROWS*COLS,1,1))
end.record()
secs = start.time_till(end)*1e-3
print(secs)

print(d_results)
```

I expect getting this-

```
array([[0.5      ],
       [0.775],
       [0.6666667],
       [0.775],
       [0.6666667],
       [0.5      ]], dtype=float32)
```

But I get this-

```
array([[0.5      ],
       [0.7777778],
       [0.6666667],
       [0.7777778],
       [0.6666667],
       [0.5      ]], dtype=float32)
```

I'm trying to understand why the particular calculation for `(7+11+13)/((7+11+13)+(2+3+4))` results with anything that is not `0.775`

Comment: You have several memory races in that kernel. It is undefined behaviour to have multiple threads write to a memory location simultaneously

Comment: @talonmies Thank you for the comment, I hope you can help with follow up questions- (1) Isn't `__syncthreads()` supposed to address this issue?; (2) Do you think I should address it per thread computation and have a `for` loop per-thread take care of that?

Comment: Thread synchronization doesn't do anything that would help here. You have multiple threads reading and writing (and potentially caching in register)  `b` and `c` and then using those in the output calculation. Unless you serialize them in some way (one calculation per thread, atomic operations, parallel reduction) this will never work. It is such a toy example I don't know what would be the best -- maybe `atomicAdd`.

Comment: Note also your use of events is incorrect. You need to synchronize on `end` before performing the time calculation. Again, this is a short running toy example so it might work by accident, but if the kernel execution time lags behind the python interpreter, I would guess you will hit a runtime errror at the `secs` calculation

Comment: @talonmies thank you! I'll do modifications and check the new results and update :)

Comment: @talonmies boom! your suggestion to use `atomicAdd` solved it! thank you so much! if you with you may submit that as an answer. Thanks so much again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted contains a memory race here:

```
int i = (bIdx * rowCount * colCount) + (tIdx * colCount);
c += permutations[i];
b += permutations[i+1];
```

Because `b` and `c` are in shared memory, you will have multiple threads attempting to read and write from/to the same memory locations simultaneously, and that is undefined behaviour in CUDA (except under extremely specific conditions which don't apply here).

If I were writing this as a toy example, I might do it like this:

```
  __global__ 
  void calc(float *permutations, int *permutationShape, float *results)
  {
    __shared__ float c;
    __shared__ float b;
    int bIdx = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;
    int tIdx = threadIdx.y * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int rowCount = permutationShape[0];
    int colCount = permutationShape[1];
    int i = (bIdx * rowCount * colCount) + (tIdx * colCount);
    atomicAdd(&c, permutations[i]);
    atomicAdd(&b, permutations[i+1]);
    __syncthreads();
    if (tIdx == 0) {
        results[bIdx] =  b / (b + c);;
    }
  }
```

In this code, `atomicAdd` ensures that the additions and memory transactions occur sequentially so that the memory race is avoided. This won't be a good solution for less trivial examples from a performance perspective (have a look at shared memory reduction techniques for that) but it should work as expected.